# How to speed up this LINQ query with join?

Tags: c#, linq, observablecollection

I have two collections of my object models that I am comparing for inequality on a per-property basis.

```
ObservableCollection<LayerModel> SourceDrawingLayers
```

...and:

```
ObservableCollection<LayerModel> TargetDrawingLayers
```

I have received great advice on creating the non-equijoin LINQ query in general and have it working in my application to great effect but now I would like to speed it up:

```
var onOffQuery = from target in TargetDrawingLayers
                 from source in SourceDrawingLayers
                 where target.Name == source.Name && target.OnOff != source.OnOff
                 select target;
```

My understanding is I am multiplying my query by the number of items in the source drawing `*` the number of items in the target drawings `*` the number of target drawings that I populated into `TargetDrawingLayers`.

I would like to speed up this operation using `Join` but I'm running into issues with the `!=` part of it.

I played around with this:

```
var newQuery = from source in SourceDrawingLayers
    join target in TargetDrawingLayers
    on target.name
    where target.OnOff != source.OnOff
    select target;
```

But I'm struggling with the syntax. Can someone set me on the right track with it?

Also, will this even be a noticeable performance improvement?

Comment: `target.OnOff != source.OnOff` is going to be a multiplication for each row that doesn't match, that's a big dataset.

Comment: Yeah that's what's killing me. On our networked environment it's taking about 30 seconds per drawing to build this comparison. Honestly it's not bad and will save a ton of time on QA but I want to get that time down if at all possible. Some of our sets will contain >200 drawings or more so obviously this is something that we want to minimize.

Comment: Is caching an option? Or can you run the query separately every 1 minute(just an example time) store that data and just grab the latest dataset?

Comment: Why not do such linking during creation of the layers? Or even on a separate thread possibly subscribe to the events of the observable collections and add them in a background process? By putting a `public object Tag { get; set; }` or even a direct named class the linking can be done, and when needed just reference `Tag`. No more  30 second processing, its done on the fly and accessed as needed.

Answer (score 5):

Replace `on target.name` with `on source.name equals target.name`

```
var newQuery = from source in SourceDrawingLayers
         join target in TargetDrawingLayers
         on source.name equals target.name
         where target.OnOff != source.OnOff
         select target;
```

---

In Linq-to-objects the join will create a [`Lookup<TKey,TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2?view=netframework-4.8) on the join properties which will result in a performance improvement when matching the `source` and `target`. Assuming that this results on a restricted result set it should improve the original code quit a bit. Of course if it results in many matches because `name` contains a very limited range of values on both sides then the performance will not be effected much at all.

As a reference please see [the link to the Enumerable.cs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,ceafecd091387688) source code that was provided in the comments below by juharr.

Comment: Thank you I will give this a try. Do you think it will be a meaningful performance improvement?

Comment: How about bench-marking to help determine if it's a *performance* improvement; the real way to do it.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ The first part of the question was about syntax which this answer provides. But please continue to go around downvoting people's answers like you seem to be doing on multiple question threads.

Comment: It really depends on the data.  If name is unique in both collections this should result in an improvement.  But if say all the items in both collecitons have only one name then this will not help at all.

Comment: Specifically this is going to create a hash on the name to help with matching up the values in the two collections (so the type of name would also effect this, I'm assuming it's a string which will work just fine).  Then it will filter those matches based on the OnOff being different.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ from the question "But I'm struggling with the syntax. Can someone set me on the right track with it?" Please tell me more about how syntax isn't involved in the question.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ glad we agree it's part of the question and that this answer provides, well an answer! I'm sure you'll remove your downvote now.

Comment: I didn't know it was an issue to down vote (we have a right) if we believe it's not helpful. IMHO, the answer lacks explanation as well, it doesn't explain anything as to *how* this solution would be an improvement and why. If I came strolling in this thread *possibly looking for a solution*, this doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: No need to argue on this newb's behalf. I'll try it out and see what happens and yeah Codexer I will benchmark it of course but I figured someone with more knowledge on this type of query would be able to give me a simple yes/no just based on experience as madreflection has so that's why I asked about the performance. No need to get touchy.

Comment: @juharr - is there a link you can provide about the creation of a hash for the join? I am searching but can't find anything.

Comment: @RickPangburn I'm not, I'm leaving constructive feedback, that's all. Also I removed all irrelevant comments to clean this thread up.

Comment: @juharr theorhetically my drawings should all have the same layers (or 99% the same layers, if a target layer is not found that matches a source layer that's actually another issue that I report on elsewhere). So yeah I am essentially still comparing every single layer from source to target.

Comment: @Igor you can check out the source code and see that it creates a `Lookup` to use https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,aecc63c3873b5c1a

Comment: @juharr - Perfect, that works. I am surprised that there is no mention of this (that I could find) in the official Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is to join on the combination of the properties `Name` and `OnOff`. The combination can be expressed as a [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple-2):

```
var newQuery = from source in SourceDrawingLayers
               join target in TargetDrawingLayers
               on (source.Name, source.OnOff) equals (target.Name, !target.OnOff)
               select target;
```